# Is local bitmap index better or normal index, if table partition is not used in query

Tags: database, oracle, database-indexes

I have a partitioned table with a column of enumerated values (i.e. non unique), and I want to make the index on this column to enhance the performance of a certain query that doesn't include the partition in the where clause (i.e. runs on the entire table) .... is it better to make it local bitmap index or a normal index ? ... I am using oracle 12g

Comment: i think you may have to try out both (local and global), maybe local index would be better i think

Comment: I noticed something , my table is partitioned by data when i am using query like date > x and date < y , like a range then bitmap index is not used by plan , only if when I am using date = X then only bitmap index ( local ) is used by plan, possibly because of local index.

Answer (score 2):

A bitmap index is better for a non-unique values like age,sex,location etc.
But it very well depends on the volume of data,size of DB and how frequent the updates are etc.

Below will be a good read.

Refer: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sharma-indexes-093638.html